# Type 'IReply' does not satisfy the constraint 'RawServerBase'. | Fastify

Tags: javascript, typescript, server

I want to use generics to infer how the response should be depending on the status code, but I don't know how to do it.

server/src/controllers/auth/login.ts:

```
import type { IReply } from '$lib/shared/interfaces';

export default async function login(
  request: FastifyRequest,
  reply: FastifyReply<IReply>,
) {
  reply.code(200).send({});
}
```

I got the this error in reply type:
`Type 'IReply' does not satisfy the constraint 'RawServerBase'.`

IReply

```
export interface IReply {
  200: {
    message: string;
    data: unknown;
  };
  400: {
    message: string;
  };
  '4xx': {
    error: string;
    message: string;
  };
  500: {
    error: string;
    message: string;
  };
}
```

server/src/routes/auth/index.ts:

```
import login from '../../controllers/Auth/login';

import type { FastifyInstance, RegisterOptions } from 'fastify';
import type { IReply } from '$lib/shared/interfaces';

export default function auth(
  fastify: FastifyInstance,
  _: RegisterOptions,
  done: (err?: Error | undefined) => void,
) {
  fastify.post('/login', login);

  done();
}
```

Comment: The docs say that I can make this:

`server.get<{
  Querystring: IQuerystring,
  Headers: IHeaders,
  Reply: IReply
}>('/auth', async (request, reply) => {` 
It works, and infers the types of what the answer would look like, but I don't know how to do it for separate files.